# Select element from two arrays with boolean array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have two numpy arrays a and b of shape (n, ) and a boolean array c, also of shape (n, ).

I want to compute a shape (n, ) numpy array x, where x[i] = a[i] if c[i], else b[i].

E.g.

```
a = np.array([3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([-1, -5, -9])
c = np.array([True, False, True])

x = np.array([3, -5, 5]).
```

Do anyone know how to do this with numpy operations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([3, 4, 5])
>>> b = np.array([-1, -5, -9])
>>> c = np.array([True, False, True])
>>>
>>> np.where(c, a, b)
array([ 3, -5,  5])
```

Using element-wise multiplication

```
>>> x = np.array([3, 4, 5])
>>> y = np.array([-1, -5, -9])
>>> c = np.array([True, False, True])

>>> x * c + y * (1 - c)
array([ 3, -5,  5])
```

Comment: Is it possible to extend this in the case where x, y are bool arrays as well?

Comment: @KatieDobbs Yes. Boolean values can be treated as 0 and 1.

Comment: @KatieDobbs I just recalled `np.where`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `zip` method towork on the three lists at the same time in your list comprehension:

```
[aa if cc else bb for aa, bb, cc in zip(a, b, c)]
```